# "Playground execution failed" when using XCPShowView(identifier: view:)

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8.1, swift-playground

When using XCPShowView the Swift Playground gives me

```
Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:

 __TF12XCPlayGround11XCPShowViewFTSSCSo6UIView_T_
```

I use `xcrun swift-demangle __TF12XCPlayGround11XCPShowViewFTSSCSo6UIView_T_` to see what's the demangled name and it's

```
XCPlayGround.XCPShowView (Swift.String,ObjectiveC.UIView) -> ()
```

(Though you can see what's the demangled name just by reading `__TF12XCPlayGround11XCPShowViewFTSSCSo6UIView_T_`)

The code is here

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayGround

let modelView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375.0, height: 667.0))

XCPShowView("modelView", modelView)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from engineer

> Engineering has the following feedback for you:
>
> In any case, this issue is addressed in the new Xcode 6,.3 seed.

Answer (score 2):

The module is called "XCPlayground", not "XCPlayGround". Symbol lookup is case sensitive. The import is probably *not* case sensitive on a standard HFS+ filesystem, so that would explain why the import works but the symbol fails to be found. Try changing it to "XCPlayground" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: No, it doesn't fix. I opened a radar while ago and they told me that it's a bug that is fixed in Xcode 6.3 beta. Well, some may experience this and some other may not. Btw, I'm using that feature in Xcode 6.3